# Getting a value using worksheetfunction.vlookup inside a VBA function NOT sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run this code and it only works when the workbook that I retrieve the data from is open, when it is closed I get a "VALUE" error from the function.

I am trying to create a custom function like Vlookup that will retrieve data from closed workbook.

here is my code:

```
Function NEWLOOKUP(lookupValue As Variant, rangeValue As String, matchValue As Integer)

Dim rangeFormat As Range
Set rangeFormat = Range(rangeValue)

NEWLOOKUP = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lookupValue, rangeFormat, matchValue, 0)

End Function
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Excel will not do this.  However, since you apparently feel confident about the location of the source (I admire your confidence), why not just open it (from VBA)?  If the open worksheet offends your aesthetics, hide it (from VBA).

Comment: I am trying to create a vlookup where the table_array is based on parameters. I have tried INDIRECT() but it's not working. I get "REF" error.